# Do the Vedas and the Upanishads support atheism(lack of belief in the existence of God or gods)?

Tags: vedas

Do the Vedas and the Upanishads support atheism(lack of belief in the existence of God or gods)? And if they support, then give reference.

Comment: Brahma Sutras talk about Nastika (aka Charvaka/Lokayata/Materialism). They don't support it.

Comment: @ram can you write an answer

Comment: Nastika is not atheist. Ton of a difference. Nastika relates to rejection of supremacy of Vedic texts. For, example, Buddhist thought and Jain literature is nastika but hardly any westerner will call it atheist. Atheism tends to go along with hedonism, reckless temporary enjoyment and the Roman concept of 'carpe diem' - live life like there's no tomorrow. Nastika is only rejection of Vedas, not rejection of the entire Indian way of life/ cultural values.

Comment: @lamThat I will edit it

Comment: Hence, it would be more helpful to specify which one you want to ask? Atheist or nastika? Even the most hedonistic text in the sanskrit language/Indian literature, the kamasutra, written by Vatsyayana recommends some 20-30 years of brahmacharya/celibacy to gain maturity and control of the senses so that one is able to enjoy hedonism properly. This fact is conveniently left out by westerners when they are looking for 'fun' in the kamasutras.

Comment: @lamThat It is atheist

Comment: If it is indeed atheist, I doubt there is much in the vedic/ upanishadic literature that supports it. There's a reference to Brihaspati as the teacher of the devas, who was a carvaka, I think. Upanishads generally relate to understanding the psychology of mind and human experience, how to optimize it, what causes suffering, the meaning of life. When you ask questions in the philosophical direction, you tend to not become a hedonist. This is true even in the western sphere, for example look at Stoicism or Epicureanism.

Comment: However, I concede that I am not well read in the original scriptures and have only read interpretations by modern Hindu spiritual leaders like Swami Vivekananda, Sri Aurobindo, Eknath Easwaran and the like. Let someone else answer it with scriptural references.

Comment: No they don't, because Upanishads say Brahman (God) created the universe. And the Nasadiya suktam is not supporting atheism either.

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by atheism. It is more finely defined in the Indian schools of philosophy then the Western catch-all term.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda There is no God are higher power.or disbelief or lack of belief in the existence of God or gods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Tejobindu Upanishad, associated with the Krishna Yajurveda, condemns atheists as follows:

> 108. This great science of Shankara should never be explained to any ordinary person, to an atheist or to a faithless, ill-behaved or
>      evil-minded person.

Although, atheism is condemned throughout Hindu scriptures, it does not mean that atheists/sceptics are unwelcome or discarded from the system.

There is an episode between Indra (here the God) and Nema (here the sceptic) in Rig Veda,  that highlights this point I made. Nema, a sceptic, does not believe in God's existence.

He says:

> "There is no Indra; who has ever seen him?" (Rig Veda 8.100.3)

Now, this is the most common objection from a sceptic. Since we can't see God why to believe in his existence?

But Indra did not get angry with Nema for saying so but instead gleefully revealed himself to Nema.

Indra says:

> Here am I, adorer! Look upon me here!. All that exists I surpass in my
> glory. The Truth make me mighty, And I also rend the worlds asunder.
> (Rig Veda 8.100.4)

This shows that everyone is welcome (in the eyes of God) and no one is discarded for their beliefs. But scriptures, overall, do condemn atheism.

Answer (score 8):

> Do vedas support atheism? Give reference from vedas and upanishades only

No they don't because they always say God (Brahman) created the universe. For example:

> [Taittiriya Upanishad](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe15/sbe15039.htm) - [Brahman] wished, may I be many, may I grow forth. He brooded over himself (like a man performing penance). After he had thus brooded, he sent forth (created) all, whatever there is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: Very interesting quote from the Tattiriya Upanishad :).This is interesting because it reminds one of the big bang theory, in which initially all was one, and later became many. However, this looks poetical rather than literal. Plus, as the brahman is without attributes, 'he wished' doesn't make sense literally, neither does 'he brooded' and 'he' created.

Comment: @IamThat That is a misconception. Brahman is saguna and not nirguna. The Upanishads in several places describe Brahman as saguna.

Comment: Ah, I see, you follow a dualistic interpretation/ dvaita vedanta. If taken literally, this verse is indeed difficult to explain by advaita vedanta interpretation.

Comment: @IamThat Yep, I think the message of the Upanishads is Vishishtadvaita Vedanta, and so I think Brahman is a sentient, personal deity with qualities.