# Why did Indra showed himself to Nema in Rigveda 8.100.4?

Tags: vedas

[Question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/44514/22556)

> There is an episode between Indra (here the God) and Nema (here the sceptic) in Rig Veda, that highlights this point I made. Nema, a sceptic, does not believe in God's existence.
>
> He says:
>
> "There is no Indra; who has ever seen him?" (Rig Veda 8.100.3)
>
> Now, this is the most common objection from a sceptic. Since we can't see God why to believe in his existence?
>
> But Indra did not get angry with Nema for saying so but instead gleefully revealed himself to Nema.
>
> Indra says:
>
> Here am I, adorer! Look upon me here!. All that exists I surpass in my glory. The Truth make me mighty, And I also rend the worlds asunder. (Rig Veda 8.100.4)
>
> This shows that everyone is welcome (in the eyes of God) and no one is discarded for their beliefs. But scriptures, overall, do condemn atheism.

**MY QUESTIONS : Why did Indra showed himself to Nema?
And what kind of karma did he did for Indra to show himself to him**?

Comment: If one sufficiently pleases a god, that god will give the worshiper his darshana.

Comment: Various people interpret the word "Nema", both ways - as a personal Noun and as an impersonal adjective. In that way, the results are different. Don't know, which is the correct way to interpret though.

Comment: @Ikshvaku "There is no Indra; who has ever seen him?" (Rig Veda 8.100.3)" I don't think someone please God by question or rejecting his existence.

Comment: @Vivikta what is the English translation of Nema as an an impersonal adjective

Comment: @DarkKnight  Nema = Not one, but many, 'Many people, as personified as a one'

Comment: @DarkKnight Ok I missed that